# How to Remove mInterstitialAd argument and set title only

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridview);

```
    sets = CategoryActivity.list.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0)).getSets();

    GridAdapter adopter = new GridAdapter(sets,getIntent().getStringExtra("title"),mInterstitialAd);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```